# PHP Redirect Email Contact

Tags: php, html, email, redirect, contacts

I'm testing a contact from with the submission on the local server. dev.localhost

The error I'm getting is

```
The requested URL /volunteer-success.php was not found on this server.
```

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to submit a form, email the message+name, and then redirect the user to a thankyou screen.

My HTML is as follows...

```
<form action="volunteer-submit.php" method="post" name="contact_form" data-parsley-validate>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="email" name="email" required>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP for sending the email is as follows

```
$to      = "example@example.com";
$subject = 'Email';
$headers = 'From: no-reply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$_POST["email"]. "\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 $message = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>';
 $message .= '<p>Hi Ben, </p>';
 $message .= '<p>'.$_POST['message'].' </p>';
 $message .= '<p>'.$_POST['email'];
 $message .= '</body></html>';



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//Redirect

header("Location:volunteer-success.php"); /* Redirect browser */

?>
```

Would love to know why it's not redirecting. I've saved the php files alongside the index.html file onto the dev.localhost.

*example emails used

Comment: "The requested URL /volunteer-success.php was not found on this server." says file isn't available on the apt location. Try doing absolute address to that file eg. header("Location:http://www.yourdomain.com/volunteer-success.php");

Comment: try to:
header("Location: /volunteer-success.php");

or:
header("Location: ./volunteer-success.php");

Comment: Is the code you've shown above in the actual volunteer-submit.php file or is it included from another file?

Comment: @Magicianred thanks! "Location: ./volunteer-success.php"); worked

Comment: btw, there needs to be a space after `Location:`, which you don't have in your example code, maybe that's the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("Location: ./volunteer-success.php");
```

Enjoy your code! :)

Comment: Hey @Magicianred any idea why the email wouldn't be sending? It takes me to the redirect page but no email is sent. I have used a proper email not the example one used above.

Comment: try if the configuration is ok:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/test-email-sending/

then try to change the character escape for new line (it's based on your server):
"\r\n" is for windows server
"\n" is for unix server

or you try with ' instead of "

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Use `exit();` after `header()`

because after redirecting page to another the code below the header shouldn't be execute.

```
header("Location: ./volunteer-success.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
```

and one more thing. check for the space in your file after and before

```
 // Before shouldn't be any space
 <?php 


  ?>
// After shouldn't be any space as well
```

Comment: to prevent any spaces after `?>` you can simply omit it. PHP will stop at the end of the file anyway, so it's often safer (because of editors appending newlines automatically) to not close the PHP tag at all.

Comment: Yes thats right. but in case of `header`. if you are using this to redirect then you need to check it all and `exit()` should be there after `header()`.

Answer (score -6):

I guess you should use javascript redirection

```
<script>window.location.href="volunteer-success.php";</script>
```

coz, most of the time php Header() won't work